# DB2 concatenated string like search parameter

Tags: sql, db2

I'm trying to return records based from people's names. I have 2 columns First Name and Last Name. I'm concatenating FirstName with a space then concatenating that result with LastName. After this, I'm trying to determine if the concatenated result is like a search parameter.

The query looks like:

```
Select * 
From tblPeopleData 
Where Upper(concat(concat(FirstName, ' '), LastName)) like '%TEST USER%'
```

But this isn't returning anything. I know the user exists in the database. Any help would be greatly appreciated! And thank you in advance!

Comment: `Where Upper(concat(FirstName, ' ', LastName)) like '%TEST USER%'`

Comment: Thank you for such a quick reply! I've tried the concat like this but received an error saying something to the tune of "No overload of concat found that uses this many parameters".

Comment: Ah, I see. Try `Where Upper(FirstName || ' ' || LastName) like '%TEST USER%'`

Comment: I'm not able to try this at the moment. I will try this when I get back to work. I will also post back my findings. Of this is the answer, could you please create answer so I would be able to accept it?

Comment: You have separate columns, why aren't you searching them as separate conditions (ie, why the concatenation)?  You may also get some false positives this way: `Louisa + May Alcott` vs `Louisa May + Alcott`.  Both the concatenation and the casing will cause the system to ignore indices.  It's possible to build computed indices, but it would be easier to do it off a single operation.  However, given that you probably want to be able to search ignoring things like accents, and culture-specific casing rules, you may need either a different collation, or application-side canonicalization.

Comment: This is for a "search engine" I'm building for a client. They asked for something like Google in the sense that there's only a textbox and a button. When the user clicks the button, the program returns almost anything containing the search criteria. So, if the user searched "uisa ma", the program would return Louisa + May Alcott and Louisa May + Alcott.

Comment: Which version and edition of DB2?

Comment: If it's going to become a large table you may want to create a secondary column that stores the concatenated, uppercase'd names, and use that for your `where` clause. This is because you want to use index to peform a text search instead of a full table scan.

`=`  >faster>  `LIKE%`  >faster> `%LIKE%'  >faster> `function()`